# iOS (iPhone/iPad) SDK - How to rotate an application from code (having troubles with UITabBarController)

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad, sdk

In my App Delegate I overrode shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation in my UITabBarController (don't worry - I didn't subclass it! ;) ) . I did it like this:

(Bottom of AppDelegate.h):

```
@interface UITabBarController (MyApp)
@end
```

(Bottom of AppDelegate.m):

```
@implementation UITabBarController (MyApp) 
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    if(self.selectedIndex==4) 
        return (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
    else
        return (toInterfaceOrientation != UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}
@end
```

Currently I have it so that when I go onto a specific tab (index 4), it will not rotate to landscape when the device is rotated (which is what I want). Although the problem is that if the application is already landscape and you tap onto that view, it is landscape (I want it to remain portrait). **(NOTE: The app rotates fine if I let it to, so working with `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` shouldn't really fix the problem (or it might))**

I've found this UITabBarController delegate method:

```
- (void)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)theTabBarController didSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)tabViewController {
    NSUInteger indexOfTab = [theTabBarController.viewControllers indexOfObject:tabViewController];
    if (indexOfTab == 4) {
        //FILL GAP HERE!
    }
}
```

I've tryed this:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarOrientation:UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait animated:YES];
```

But it only rotates the status bar - not the whole app. Is there some method (or anything) in UITabBarController that'll rotate it to portrait to fill in the gap above?

Sorry if it isn't too confusing for anyone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Used `transform` and `setStatusBarOrientation` - although it has some side effects (will have to do for now).

Answer (score 0):

Just implement shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:toInterfaceOrientation: for the view controller used in tab you dont want to rotate, and make sure it returns NO for the non-valid orientation(s).

Comment: I tried that but it didn't work. It seems that `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation` only gets called when it is going to rotate, not when it's already rotated.